# Django: access attributes of queryset using index notation not dot notation?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

When I try to do this in Django:

```
organisms = Organism.objects.filter(code=c)
fields = ['name', 'linnean_type', 'age'] # in reality there are more
for o in organisms:
    for f in fields:
        print o[f]
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError 'Organism' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Is there a way that I can access the attributes of each result in the queryset without using dot notation?

Comment: `getattr(object, attribute)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `[]` notation, internally, Python will try to invoke `__getitem__` method on that object. Since the `Organism` object didn't define that method, it fails with that error.

Instead, you can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function, like this

```
print getattr(o, f)
```

You can even specify a default value to be used if the attribute is not present in the object, like this

```
print getattr(o, f, "{} not present in {}".format(f, o))
```